# manage trial users in customer portal

Tags: apex

We want to give access to our environment for a trial period of 30 days.

What would be the best way to achieve this? The users could be using Gold partner, chatter free user or any license depending upon the access to various custom and standard objects.

The way i thought was to run a scheduled batch apex to run everyday to check if the user has exceeded 30 days from created date or have a custom field called custom field activation date and check if the date difference between this date and todays date is > 30 days then deactivate the user.

These users should also be able to activated once they make a payment.

In the documentation for deactivating an user

> If you deactivate a user, any EntitySubscription where the user is associated with the ParentId or CreatedBy field, meaning all subscriptions both to and from the user, are soft deleted. If the user is reactivated, the subscriptions are restored. However, if you deactivate multiple users at once and these users follow each other, their subscriptions are hard deleted. In this case, the user-to-user EntitySubscription is deleted twice (double deleted). Such subscriptions can’t be restored upon user reactivation.

Is it not right to bulk deactivate users?

Is the approach of running a schedule batch to check if the user has exceeded the trial period the best approach? are there any other approaches i can consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say your approach is the correct one.  The document snippet you are referring to is regarding the deletion of several users that follow each other on chatter, so you'd have to accept that you couldn't re-instate that particular piece of configuration. Unless, that is, you captured it and stored it elsewhere and re-applied it on activation.  Its probably easier to make the users aware that they'd have to re-follow users when they buy the real access.

Comment: Thanks  Bob.. Just wanted to be sure i was in the right track.